# Disable splitpane divider movement in one particular direction

Tags: java

I have a vertical split pane. The top portion contains a table and the bottom portion contains a JInternalFrame that displays console.

I want to restrict the movement of the divider in the downward direction i.e the divider can be moved upwards but cannot be moved down. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the minimum size of the bottom component.